# Unable to change shell in Android Studio terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal, macos-big-sur

My system terminal is using `zsh` shell but my Android Studio terminal is using `bash`.
On running

```
echo $SHELL
```

System Terminal prints:

> /bin/zsh

Android Studio Terminal prints:

> /bin/bash

I tried changing the shell in Android Studio Terminal using:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

But it doesn't change the shell. Here's the commands I ran:

```
iDecodes-mac:example iDecode$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
Changing shell for iDecode.
Password for iDecode:
chsh: no changes made
iDecodes-mac:example iDecode$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 5):

This is for Mac
Go to Android studio -> Preference -> Terminal -> shell path and select /bin/bash -> apply -> ok

Comment: Im using Android Studio on Linux and that fits to me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, go to `File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal`. You should be able to see a `Shell path` field with the bash path as the default shell. Replace it with the path of your zsh there. Ideally, it should be `/usr/bin/zsh`. Save and close. Reopen your IDE terminal and it should now default to zsh.